# Get-ChildItem | tree gives me a wierdly formatted tree

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

The following input:

```
PS STG:\> Get-ChildItem | tree
```

Gives me

```
Folder PATH listing for volume Data
Volume serial number is 6576-C540
D:.
ÃÄÄÄAPK
ÃÄÄÄAssets
³   ÃÄÄÄAnimations
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄCharacters
³   ³   ³   ÀÄÄÄinhabitant
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄEnvironment
³   ³   ÀÄÄÄProps
³   ÃÄÄÄMaterials
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄCharacters
³   ³   ³   ÀÄÄÄinhabitant
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄEnvironment
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄParticles
³   ³   ³   ÀÄÄÄasteroidParticle
³   ³   ÀÄÄÄProps
³   ÃÄÄÄMeshes
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄCharacters
³   ³   ³   ÀÄÄÄinhabitant
³   ³   ÃÄÄÄEnvironment
³   ³   ÀÄÄÄProps
```

...etc.

When I was expecting something formatted more like:

```
├───APK
├───Assets
    └───Animations
    |   └───Characters
    |   |   └───inhabitant
    |   ├───Environment
    |   └───Props
    └───Materials
    |   └───Characters
    |   |   └───inhabitant
    |   ├───Environment
    |   └───Particles
    |   |   └───asteroidParticle
    |   └───Props
    └───Meshes
        └───Characters
        |   └───inhabitant
        ├───Environment
        └───Props
```

What am I doing / understanding wrong?

This is the value of `$OutputEncoding`:

```
IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Western European (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252`
```

Comment: @MHA, please copy the detail into your original post - [the post can be edited](http://superuser.com/posts/745083/edit).

Comment: It definitely looks like an encoding problem.  My tree works and the encoding is us-ascii.  IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : us-ascii
EncodingName      : US-ASCII
HeaderName        : us-ascii
WebName           : us-ascii
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : False
IsBrowserSave     : False
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 20127

Comment: Im trying to find a way to change to code page... not having much luck, but Im sure thats the issue

Comment: @Keltari - you can change the output encoding with `$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(<code page>)`, but I am not able to repro OP's issue by setting the code page to `1252`

Comment: @MHA Does using the ascii switch for tree help? `gci| tree /A`

Comment: There is also `chcp` to get and set the console's code page, but I was not able to see any change in the display by changing it. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490874.aspx

Comment: Tree isn't a powershell command that I know of, and doesn't accept piped input. `tree` by itself should give you the tree you want.

Comment: @Eris Tree is available in PowerShell community extensions. However, the OP hasn't explicitly mentioned whether they're using that or if PowerShell is falling back to CMD's tree command.

Comment: @MHA - Please provide the output of `Get-Command tree`.

Comment: Since I asked this questions I have moved to a different machine. When I run "tree" it works as intended. Thank you for your input. If you formulate it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The default Command Prompt console encoding is codepage 437 and tree.com uses extended characters by default. PowerShell ISE's default console output codepage is 1252. Here are some ways to get around this:

1. Use `tree.com /A` to force tree to use ASCII instead of extended characters.
2. Change the console output encoding in PowerShell to codepage 437 with `chcp 437; [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(437)`.
3. Convert to bytes and re-encode the output from `tree.com | %{ [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('IBM437').GetString([Console]::OutputEncoding.GetBytes($_)) }`

Note that option 2 may have impacts on how some other things display.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of PowerShell and the presence or absence of community extensions, you can actually end up calling C:\Windows\System32\tree.com. The gibberish is because PowerShell is not using the correct encoding to display the extended characters that tree.com uses by default. You can use chcp.com to see what the command processor's current code page setting is. The usual default is code page 437. PowerShell uses code page 1252 by default. There are to options for dealing with this that work well and are both low-impact and simple.

1. Just use tree '/A'.
2. Convert the output from tree to bytes and load it with the proper
   code page using the following code:

`tree | %{ [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('IBM437').GetString($OutputEncoding.GetBytes($_)) }`

Answer (score 1):

`tree` does not do what you think it does.

`tree` is not a PowerShell cmdlet. It wasn’t back when this question was asked and it isn’t now on PowerShell 5.1.  It is a DOS command. *It does not accept any input.* When you do `gci | tree`, you are not using the output of `Get-ChildItem` at all.

The only correct solution is not to use `tree` but a proper PowerShell cmdlet instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Show-Tree](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/06/06/powertip-view-directory-list-as-tree-by-using-powershell.aspx) commandlet.

```
09:17 $ Show-Tree C:\Chocolatey\ -Depth 1
C:\Chocolatey\
|--bin
\--lib
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you running the command in Powershell or Powershell ISE?

There's a difference.

This is what I get in Powershell ISE:

```
PS C:\powershell> Get-ChildItem | tree
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is XXXX-XXXX
C:.
ÃÄÄÄFolder 1
³   ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 1
³   ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 2
³   ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 3
³   ÀÄÄÄSubfolder 4
ÃÄÄÄFolder 2
³   ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 1
³   ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 2
³   ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 3
³   ÀÄÄÄSubfolder 4
ÃÄÄÄFolder 3
³   ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 1
³   ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 2
³   ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 3
³   ÀÄÄÄSubfolder 4
ÀÄÄÄFolder 4
    ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 1
    ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 2
    ÃÄÄÄSubfolder 3
    ÀÄÄÄSubfolder 4

PS C:\powershell>
```

This is what I get in Powershell:

```
PS C:\powershell> Get-childitem | tree
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is XXXX-XXXX
C:.
+---Folder 1
¦   +---Subfolder 1
¦   +---Subfolder 2
¦   +---Subfolder 3
¦   +---Subfolder 4
+---Folder 2
¦   +---Subfolder 1
¦   +---Subfolder 2
¦   +---Subfolder 3
¦   +---Subfolder 4
+---Folder 3
¦   +---Subfolder 1
¦   +---Subfolder 2
¦   +---Subfolder 3
¦   +---Subfolder 4
+---Folder 4
    +---Subfolder 1
    +---Subfolder 2
    +---Subfolder 3
    +---Subfolder 4

PS C:\powershell>
```

Comment: Interesting point here, but I must say my experience differs - tree output is the same regardless of using console or ISE. Do you have the community extensions installed, or is this using CMD's tree?