# "Help Tree" returns help for Copy-Item

Tags: powershell

In doing some research on [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/745083/get-childitem-tree-gives-me-a-wierdly-formatted-tree), I wanted to check to be sure that `tree` was not an actual native PowerShell command or alias. Of course, the proper way to do this is with `Get-Command`. However, when I'm looking up a command I'm not sure of, I usually prefer to go straight to the help file if it exists instead of doing a two-step of "check if the command exists, *then* go to help". So, the command I ran was `help tree`. To my surprise, it returned the help file for Copy-Item!

As a sanity check, I spelled it out - `Get-Help tree` - but ended up with the same results. To see if `tree` was, for some odd reason, an alias for `Copy-Item` I ran `gal tree` - this returned an error saying such alias does not exist. I ran `gal -def Copy-Item` to check all aliases for `Copy-Item`, and it only pulled up `copy`, `cp`, and `cpi`.

Finally, I did `gcm tree` to see what PowerShell was actually supposed to be using for `tree`. This turned up, as I expected, a CommandType of "Application" with Definition "C:\Windows\system32\tree.com".

Unfortunately, none of this answers for the unusual behavior of `Get-Help` here. Why would `Get-Help tree` return the help file for `Copy-Item`, when the two appear entirely unrelated? This behavior has been duplicated in PowerShell 2.0 on Windows 7 SP1, and PowerShell 4.0 on Windows 8.1.

[image]

Comment: Im not getting this... http://snag.gy/Zbz71.jpg

Comment: @soandos You must have some custom module(s) installed. As far as I can tell, Show-Tree is not a native PowerShell command. The first [Google result](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/06/06/powertip-view-directory-list-as-tree-by-using-powershell.aspx) seems to point to the PowerShell Community Extensions.

Comment: I just tried using Windows 7 SP1 / PowerShell 2.0. I can reproduce the same behavior using an US English locale, but I get an `HelpNotFoundException` error with a different one. I don't know if other English locales are affected.

Comment: @Iszi my get command for tree returns the same thing as yours

Comment: @soandos Try `gal -def Show-Tree`

Comment: @Iszi `gal : This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the definition 'Show-Tree' does not exist`

Comment: @soandos Found an explanation for your situation. When the string provided to `Get-Help` is enough to partially match the command of exactly one help entry, Get-Help will return that the help for that command. In your case, the only help entry matching "tree" would (probably) be `Show-Tree`. Example: `Help ModuleMe` is enough to return the help for `Export-ModuleMember` if no custom modules containing similarly-named cmdlets are installed. This behavior may or may not also be related to my issue, but right now I can't see how.

Comment: @Iszi H'm, I'll look into it on other machines then.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this result because the help for Copy-Item is the **only** help file in your system that contains the keyword "tree". The following command will show that the string "tree" occurs in the remarks of the examples section.

```
(Get-Help -Name Copy-Item).examples.example.remarks | Where-Object { $_ -match 'tree'}
```

Try the below command and you'll find that the keyword "intact" is unique to that help file too.

```
Get-Help intact
```

This also explains that it is not found using another locale.

For example, for a list of help files containing the keyword "particular", use the command

```
Get-Help particular
```

I hope this clarifies the usage.

Comment: Could you point to, and perhaps include an excerpt of, the part that includes "tree"? I'm having a hard time finding it.

Comment: Sure, edited the answer to include that.

Comment: And marking it as an answer would be gracious.